# Spring Kafka (2.2.7.RELEASE) with. kafka-clients:2.2.1 IOException during embedded broker startup

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

Driven by a dependency-check warning we tried to bump the version of org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients to version 2.2.1 in our setup, using spring-kafka:2.2.7.

As a result the tests using EmbeddedKafkaRule fail during broker startup with an IOException claiming "Failed to load /some/path.."

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to load /Users/[..]/target/embedded-kafka during broker startup
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:152)
at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createAndValidateLogDirs$1.apply(LogManager.scala:149)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at kafka.log.LogManager.createAndValidateLogDirs(LogManager.scala:149)
at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:80)
at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:953)
at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:237)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:132)
at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)
at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:223)
at org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule.before(EmbeddedKafkaRule.java:109)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

We made sure, to have no conflicting version of kafka-clients on the classpath and also tried to specify the logs.dir of the EmbeddedKafkaRule to some folder under maven's target folder, "target/embedded-kafka" in the above example. 
Both with no success.

Did anybody have the same issue and resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it without any problems.

Did you follow the instructions in [the documentation about overriding kafka client versions?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x).

> When you use spring-kafka-test (version 2.2.x) with the 2.1.x kafka-clients jar, you need to override certain transitive dependencies, as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Note that when switching to scala 2.12 (recommended for 2.1.x and higher), the 2.11 version must be excluded from spring-kafka-test.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I was not aware of the specific documentation. It solved my problem!